# HTML, CSS - Styling Lists - Best practices

Tags: html, css

I am looking to style a list in HTML / CSS, and wondering what best practices are.

```
<ul class="newsItems">
    <li>
        <h5>July 16, 2012</h5>
        <p>News - headline information</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to display a small newspaper icon, along with the text in the H5 and the P alongside to the right of it, and these need to be displayed inline (left to right).

Is it best to do this with an LI containing the H5 / P elements, or is there a much better way of doing this that I don't know about?

My CSS currently looks something like this :-

```
#News .newsItems {
padding-left:10px;
display:inline;
}

#News .newsItems li {
list-style-image:url(/Images/NewspaperIcon.png);    
list-style-position:Inside;
}

#News .newsItems li {
vertical-align:top;
max-width:180px;
}

#News .newsItems li h5 {
vertical-align:top;
}

#News .newsItems li p {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

An example of the intended output -

[image: List Items - News]

Comment: Could you add an image of an expected output? I don't understand it from your explanation.

Comment: I was thinking here: would a definition list fits better in this case? The `<dt>` with the date, the `<dd>` with the description.

Comment: Definition list is a good shout - definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**CSS**

```
ul.newsItems{
margin:0; padding:0;
}
ul.newsItems li {    
  height:auto; 
  display:inline-block; 
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:40px; max-width:180px;
 background: url('http://www.parker.edu/uploadedImages/1200_Newsletters/1214_Buttons/Newsletter-Icon.png') left top no-repeat;
}
.newsItems li span{
vertical-align:top; font-weight:bold;
}
.newsItems li p  {margin:0; padding:0}
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/Y7JLL8Tc)**

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot. Was it the <H5> that was causing me issues?